# Cannot access object properties from dynamic import. Vue.js + ts

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-component, dynamic-import

My customer wants to have other instances of the app with another content as well (so called 'themes'). We decided to use env variable + prefilled object with content. So, this content may exist or it may not.
I created a function that conditionally imports module with all the content and it actually even working:

```
theme: string;
hasAnyTheme: boolean;

static getThemedMiscContent(): {[key: string]: string} {
    let miscContent = {};
      if (hasAnyTheme) {
          import(`@/themes/customers-themes/${theme}/ThemedContent`)
            .then(themedContent => {
              miscContent = Object.assign(miscContent, themedContent.ThemedMiscContent);
            });
    }
    return miscContent;
  }
```

But when I call it from the component, I can't actually read properties of the object while I can read the object itself.

```
// computed
miscThemedContent(): {[key: string]: string} {
  return ThemeUtil.getThemedMiscContent();
}

// template
{{ miscThemedContent }} // is totally fine
{{ miscThemedContent.someValue }} // undefined
```

And as the weird fact, this issue appears in only one of my 3 components that use that function. Others work just fine.
As far, as I understood, that kind of error appears when Vue tries to use that value before the object is loaded. So, I tried to add additional loading variable and nothing is happening. Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `import` is an async function, `miscContent` could be returned before the import function's execution is completed. I suggest you make use of `async/await` syntax to wait for the actual result before returning the `miscContent`, it should be something like this:

```
static async getThemedMiscContent(): {[key: string]: string} {
    let miscContent = {};
      if (hasAnyTheme) {
          const importTheme = await import(`@/themes/customers-themes/${theme}/ThemedContent`);
          if (importTheme && importTheme.ThemedMiscContent) {
              miscContent = Object.assign(miscContent, importTheme.ThemedMiscContent);
          }
    }
    return miscContent;
  }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Works as intended after adapting my code to promise, thank you! Don't have enough rating to show my upvote, but it is scored.